# What figure-of-merit (FoM) is used to characterize the performance of a launch system's reentry-and-landing system?

Tags: reentry, launch-vehicle, cost-to-orbit

I'd like to make a table that compares the performance of different launch systems such as The Space Shuttle, Falcon 9 plus Crew Dragon, and Starship. Engine ISP and thrust-to-weight ratio would be important metrics for launch. Another relevant performance metric might be the ratio of the rocket's dry mass to its wet mass or its payload.

However, all three of the aforementioned systems allocate a significant portion of the total mass that reaches orbit to *reentry-and-landing system components*, including, for example, wings, thermal tiles, head shields, propellant for landing burns, parachutes, landing gear, flaps, etc.

My first guess is that the figure of merit for a reentry-and-landing system would be something like...

$$\epsilon = (m_O - m_D - m_P)/m_O$$

Where:

$\epsilon$ is the reentry-and-landing system figure-of-merit (smaller is better),

$m_O$ is the total mass of everything that achieves a circular orbit,

$m_D$ is the dry mass of everything that was essential for achieving the circular orbit, and

$m_P$ is the mass of the payload.

Is there a reentry-and-landing system figure-of-merit like this that has already been established within the rocket launch industry and, if so, has it been documented anywhere?

Comment: As an aside it depends who is asking. If its any sort of engineer then you're right, but if it's any sort of politician then all bets are off.

Comment: A figure-of-merit is a communication tool. As with all communication, it depends on *what* you want to communicate *to whom*. Think about CPUs, there are all sorts of different figures-of-merit: clock frequency, core count, thread count, operations/s, operations/cycle, operations/W, operations/$. Or think about launch vehicles: you have I_sp, TWR, mass fraction, payload to orbit, reliability, etc. SpaceX believe the most important and most relevant one is cost per kilogram to orbit, which however is a metric only SpaceX uses, nobody else.

Comment: as someone who came-of-degree during the "shuttle was a mistake, reusability is a dream, let's put a capsule on a long SRB what could go wrong" era of aerospace thought, fleet lifetime mass-specific-cost-to-orbit certainly makes an impression. Because of large fixed ongoing staffing costs in aerospace it also wraps up a number of turnaround and program efficiency metrics into one number. Unfortunately it's going to be guesswork at best for anything in development

Comment: @erinanne raises an interesting point. There's going to be an FoM that is really doesn't care about cost and another, potentially more relevant FoM that *does care* about cost. As we learned from the Space Shuttle, the cost of inspecting and refurbishing the thermal protection system was significant.